# Android: Disable CORS using a ContentProvider in Crosswalk

Tags: android, cors, openlayers-3, crosswalk

I am currently implementing ***OpenLayers*** in a native Android App using Crosswalk.
In my *assets* folder, I have my html/js and json(manifest) files.

I load the OpenLayers map through:

```
webview.loadAppFromManifest("file:///android_asset/map_home.json", null);
```

The JSON file points to the html file, which includes the necessary js files to run OpenLayers.
I run a special map from The Danish Geodata Agency (http://eng.gst.dk/). The map wouldn't load on some Android devices when I was using the standard webview. As a result I have implemented the Crosswalk webview.

This is causing me some troubles with CORS. First I got errors when loading the special map.

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(425)] "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at http://kortforsyningen.kms.dk/topo_geo?ticket=6015626e0d3b87b75358b1bf8c64d55a&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&LAYERS=Vejnavn&STYLES=default&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A25832&BBOX=718835.2000000001%2C6176979.2%2C718886.4%2C6177030.4 may not be loaded.", source: file:///android_asset/ol.js (425)
```

I solved this by adding http/https addresses as trusted hosts in the json manifest:

```
{
  "name": "map_home",
  "start_url": "map_home.html",
  "xwalk_hosts": [
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ]
}
```

As explained in: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/manifest/xwalk_hosts.html

This allowed me to load the map without CORS errors.

Next I am adding markers/features to the map. When I was trying to load local image files for the markers, my app ended in a crash/reboot loop. I found (and lost) a link, which recommended using a content provider to access local files. This seems the be working but once again I get a CORS error.

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(391)] "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at content://dk.pernexus.markers/43.png may not be loaded.", source: file:///android_asset/ol.js (391)
```

I have tried to add "content://*/" as an "xwalk_hosts", but still get the same error.

```
{
  "name": "map_home",
  "start_url": "map_home.html",
  "xwalk_hosts": [
    "content://*/",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to allow "content://" or completely disable CORS-checks with Crosswalk?

In the standard Android Webview I was able to enable to following setting:

```
webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

This configuration is not present with Crosswalk.

I am using the following versions:

- minSdkVersion 19 (Android 4.4)
- Crosswalk 15.44.384.13 (also tried the newest beta: 17.46.448.3)
- OpenLayers 3.12.1

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem is no longer urgent.
I got my program to load files directly from the file system without a contentprovider.
My original problem was that when Crosswalk loaded an OpenLayers map with a renderer specified as 'webgl' crashed silently, when features which included icons, were added.
Changing to the default renderer solved this problem.

The above problem with "content://" being blocked by CORS still persist.